# Conditional List Render for Data to match API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, conditional-statements

I am a beginner in at Vue.js version 2.6.11.

I am having trouble sending a POST request to an API. The create request has conditional nested JSON data and I'm not sure how to send this in Vue. I cannot change the API.

The choices for example are:

```
          "diet": {
            "vegetarian": boolean,
            "carnivore": boolean,
            "seeds": "boolean"
          }
```

But it can only be one of the three choices

```
          "diet": {
            "vegetarian": true, //can be true or false
          }
```

```
          "diet": {
            "carnivore": true, //can be true or false
          }
```

```
          "diet": {
            "seeds": true, //can be true or false
          }
```

How do we write this in data() in a diet.vue file?

```
 data () {
    return {
      diet: {
       vegeterian: this.dietType
      },
```

I can't add an if statement in the return directly, it gives me syntax errors

```
 data () {
    return {
      diet: {
         if (true){
            vegeterian: this.dietType
         },
     
      },
```

Thank you, please let me know if you have any suggestions/ideas!

Comment: Hi, Try using computed property instead of using data. `computed: { diet () {  if(true) vegeterian: this.dietType;  }  }`

Comment: What you write in `data` is pure JS. Consider doing a research on how things are done there. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it can be a ternary instead of `if`, or else. It's unclear where `dietType` comes from. It's ok if it's a prop, otherwise you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Ah I think my comment was deleted. But yes this.dietType was a prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did a example on how to send a payload with in `data` related data.

its a litte shot in the dark because i did't understand your purpose but i think you need to send the computed `postPayload` in your post request.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px"
      >vegetarian: {{ diet.vegetarian }}</label
    >
    <button @click="diet.vegetarian = !diet.vegetarian">toggle</button>
    <br />

    <label style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px"
      >vegetarian: {{ diet.carnivore }}</label
    >
    <button @click="diet.carnivore = !diet.carnivore">toggle</button>
    <br />

    <label style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px"
      >vegetarian: {{ diet.seeds }}</label
    >
    <button @click="diet.seeds = !diet.seeds">toggle</button>

    <hr />
    <br />
    <h4>Your Payload for your Post</h4>
    {{ postPayload }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      diet: {
        vegetarian: false,
        carnivore: false,
        seeds: false,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    postPayload: function () { // <---- you need to send this obj in your post
      return {
        vegetarian: this.diet.vegetarian,
        carnivore: this.diet.carnivore,
        seeds: this.diet.seeds,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

you can play with this example here in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-star-ze4un?file=/src/App.vue:0-1289)

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet! Yes need to send the postPayload to the POST request.